# reponse.Redirect() generates 404 error on tomcat7

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, response

I have servlet that dispatches jsp files for a loggin project, the logic works fine but I am not getting the right jsp, but an error instead:

```
            if (user.isValid())//isValid UserDAO
            { 
                HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
                session.setAttribute("currentSessionUser",user);


                response.sendRedirect("/Logggedin.jsp"); //logged-in page
                //System.out.println("You are logged in");

            }
             else 
             {
                 response.sendRedirect("/InvalidLogin.jsp"); //error page } 

                 //System.out.println("You are not logged in");
             }
```

Note that my base path is /ClassGrading/*, I tried both paths: ClassGradking/Loggedin.jsp and the one above, within the index.jsp page I have the following code:

```
          <form action="LoginServlet">
```

Comment: try removing the slash in path name like "Logggedin.jsp" n "InvalidLogin.jsp"

Comment: Is it supposed to be `Logggedin.jsp`, or `Loggedin.jsp`? Is there a typo in your SO question, in your actual code, both, neither?

Answer (score 1):

404 means file not found.I am not aware of the location of Logggedin.jsp and InvalidLogin.jsp

But I think you should do `response.sendRedirect("Logggedin.jsp"); //logged-in page`
 and `response.sendRedirect("InvalidLogin.jsp"); //error page }`

Remove the `/`

From the OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422168/reponse-redirect-generates-404-error-on-tomcat7/21422204?noredirect=1#comment32318757_21422204)

The jsp and html files should be outside **WEB-INF** folder

Lets say your project name is **test**, then all class files(.class) files will be inside `WEB-INF/classes`.

All jar files should be inside `WEB-INF/lib`.`Web.xml` should be inside `WEB-INF` and all jsp/html files should be outside `WEB-INF`

[Apache tomcat file deployement](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html)

Comment: A reference to the javadoc would help.

Comment: The loggedin.jsp is located within WebContent in a dynamic j2ee application, is that a problem using the response object?

Comment: @user1712095 try my way.If you still find error then post the file structure

Comment: I tried your way, file structure: WebContent/WEB-INF/Loggedin.jsp,      <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ClassGrading/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

Comment: In which folder have you kept jsp files?

Comment: straight in WEB-INF of WenContent

Comment: @user1712095 all jsp files should be outside web-inf folder